# How to find vector that is in the same plane and perperndicular to a side of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

Suppose we have a triangle ABC. How does one find a vector E that is in the same plane as the triangle and is perpendicular to segment BC?
I know that a dot product is 0 when two vectors are perpendicular. i.e.: $$(B-C)\cdot(B-E)=0$$ How do I account for the fact that vector is in the same plane as ABC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec{ac} \wedge \vec{bc}$ is a bivector representing the plane that the triangle resides in.  Then to collapse the dimension parallel to $\vec {bc}$, just use left contraction: $\vec{bc}\ \raise .2em{\lrcorner}\ (\vec{ac} \wedge \vec{bc})$.  Then you'll have such a vector.

---

Or doing it your way:  $(c-b)\cdot(e-b)=0$ gives you a vector $\vec{be}$ orthogonal to $\vec{bc}$, but you also want it orthogonal to a vector orthogonal to the plane containing the triangle.

A vector orthogonal to that plane can be found by $\vec{ab}\times\vec{bc}$. So you just need to solve the system of equations $\begin{cases} \vec{bc}\cdot\vec{be} =0 \\ (\vec{bc}\times\vec{ab})\cdot \vec{be}=0\end{cases}$

---

Or another way of doing it is $\vec v = \vec {ab} - \operatorname{proj}_{\vec{bc}}\vec{ab}$, where $\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{bc}}\vec{ab}$ is the projection of $\vec{ab}$ onto the subspace spanned by $\vec{bc}$.

Comment: sorry but what does symbol $\lrcorner$ mean?

Comment: It's the symbol for left contraction which is a generalization of the dot product of vectors.  Basically, there is a more general product between vectors (and more general objects named multivectors) called the *geometric product*, which is simply denoted by $\vec u\vec v$ (or $AB$ for multivectors $A$ and $B$).  Left contraction is defined by $\langle \vec u\vec v\rangle_0$ (or $\sum_i \sum_j \langle\langle A\rangle_i \langle B\rangle_j\rangle_{j-i}$ in general), where $\langle \cdot \rangle_{x}$ is the grade $x$ components of your object.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the cross product of your two vectors you will get a vector that is perpendicular to the plane of the triangle. Then take this new vector and take the cross product it with your original vector. The vector that is perpendicular to these will be back on your original plane, and will also be perpendicular to your original vector.